# Postgres case statment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working with some of my teacher's old Postgres SQL code and modifying it to match what I need. However, there is one piece of code that I can't seem to find an explanation of anywhere online. In the code he had a case statement with a ~~* used as what looked like a comparison. I am unfamiliar with this syntax and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
CASE
        WHEN sessions.status ~~* 'data%finder%'::text THEN ((sessions.minutes_in_data_ || ' ('::text) || sessions.minutes_in_idle) || ')'::text
        WHEN sessions.status ~~* 'text%edit%'::text THEN ((sessions.minutes_in_text_editor || ' ('::text) || sessions.minutes_in_idle) || ')'::text
        WHEN sessions.status ~~* 'admin%module%'::text AND sessions.minutes_in_module<> 0 THEN ((sessions.minutes_in_module|| ' ('::text) || sessions.minutes_in_idle) || ')'::text
        WHEN sessions.status ~~* 'client%module%'::text AND sessions.minutes_in_module<> 0 THEN ((sessions.minutes_in_module|| ' ('::text) || sessions.minutes_in_idle) || ')'::text
        ELSE NULL::text
    END AS "Duration (Idle)",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent to `like`/`ilike`:

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-matching.html)

> The operator ~~ is equivalent to LIKE,
>   and ~~* corresponds to ILIKE. There
>   are also !~~ and !~~* operators that
>   represent NOT LIKE and NOT ILIKE,
>   respectively. All of these operators
>   are PostgreSQL-specific.

Comment: Check this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-matching.html